# Is there a way to parse a T-SQL select statement with the "Oslo" M runtime?

Tags: t-sql, oslo

Searching around the Microsoft.M assembly I found the SourceParser class and whole set of classes in the Microsoft.TSQL10 namespace that seem related to parsing SQL but I cannot find examples of how to use it.

I know the you can generate T-SQL easily enough, but can you consume it, manipulate the data structure and re-output a modified version of the SQL select?

Answer (score 0):

No is apparently the answer.  I received confirmation of this on the MSDN forums.